# Download Progress Bar as LinearLayout Background

Tags: android

I have an app where students at my school can download course content that professors upload. Everything works great, except I have no progress bar dialog. I recently switched the app over to using fragments, so the old dialog I was using broke.

Anyway, I was thinking that instead of having a dialog display the progress bar, I could use the background of the item that was clicked as the progress bar.

Here is a screenshot of the app: 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4439149/Screenshot_2012-09-27-15-06-43.png

And here is a mocup of how I imagine it working:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4439149/42an8-CTWBJpw391zDSBs5MAiuIhibcsRWhZGwdvmTE%20copy.png

I cannot for the life of me think of how this should be done.  I am hoping someone could just give me a push in the right direction.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Clip Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip).  You can set the background of your row to a ClipDrawable that holds the color or another drawable that you want to show for progress, then set the level (progress) while downloading.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I was looking for.  I will try and implement this later today.  I'm curious as to what would happen if you defined the clip drawable using a color drawable. I have a feeling it wouldn't work since a color drawable doesn't have dimensions.

Anyway, thanks a lot. This really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your `row.xml` to be a frame layout and just have a `ProgressBar` that  fills the entire row?  You can then put this behind the layout you currently have in your row.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I think the Clip Drawable that Chris recommend will be better for me.